# Is it possible to call the main method passing args[] from another method?

Tags: java

I'm trying to call the main method of a class from another method passing arguments like when running the class from the command line. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @EJP - couldn't agree with you more.  This question could have trivially been checked out (probably faster than posting the question).

Comment: A lot faster than posting the question, and orders of magnitudes faster than waiting for the answer ... which might *never* arrive.

Comment: @abcdefg, why haven't you yet accepted your answer?

Answer (score 23):

You can call the `main` method as you would call any other (static) method:

```
MyClass.main(new String[] {"arg1", "arg2", "arg3"});
```

Example:

```
class MyClass {
    public static void test() {
        MyClass.main(new String[] {"arg1", "arg2", "arg3"});
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for (String s : args)
            System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Yes, the main method can be called like any other method, so if you have a class Test with a main method, you can call it from any other class like:

```
Test.main(new String[] { "a", "b" });
```

and this way you'll pass "a" and "b" as the parameters.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried something like :

```
// In your method
String[] yourArgs = new String[] {"foo", "baz", "bar"};
YourClassWithMain.main(yourArgs);
```

But I think this is not a good idea, the main() method should only contain some very basic code which calls the constructor. You shouldn't call it directly, but rather create a new instance of your other class which will do all the initialization needed.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is yes,

Since `main` is a `static` method and is **public** method, you can do this (and it compiled on my case):

```
/**
 * @author The Elite Gentleman
 *
 */
public class Test {

    /**
     * 
     */
    public Test() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        Test.main(new String[] {"main"}); //Yes, it works and compiles....
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Hello");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can call the `main`-method just as an ordinary (static) method like this:

```
TheClass.main(new String[] { "lorem", "ipsum" });
```

As a side note, you could declare the main method like this:

```
public static void main(String... args) { ... }
```

and call it like

```
TheClass.main("lorem", "ipsum");
```

The bytecode produced is the same (varargs are compiled to arrays), so it is backward compatible in all ways (except that it won't compile on non-vararg aware java-compilers).

Answer (score 0):

You could just rename your main and make a new one, making it call the "new" main. At least that's what I generally do when unit testing

Comment: unit testing should NOT require you to change your methods, this is a very bad way of doing things

Comment: I didn't make it clear but I pretty much never have a main that does more than parse arguments and pass them on to something else, because a clunky main is just a bad idea. Also, changing code for testing is not a good idea, however you should be writing testable code in the first place