# How to give a programmatic support to a class with a main

Tags: java

I'm sorry for the title but I can't really find another way to express it. I need to create a class with a double function, if you give to it a file as input from the console or terminal it gives back a print of it's calculations, but the class can be also used as subroutine and give a file to another class for further calculation.

To implement the first task I must define a main to accept input from console like this

```
java MyClass myfile.file
```

But then I can not simply get an instance the class inside something else like this

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(file);
```

cause I will always get an error from the main(IndexOutOfBound since args it's just an empty array).

How can I fix this? I must use the same class to do so, I can not build another class for the subroutine function.

Comment: Show us your code, and the stack trace of the exception you get. The main method is not called when constructing an instance of a class, so your description of the problem makes no sense.

Comment: You're right it was some problem with eclipse, I've closed it and restart it and everything went fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to call the main method passing args\[\] from another method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122455/is-it-possible-to-call-the-main-method-passing-args-from-another-method)

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
public class MyClass {
   public MyClass(String nameOfFile) {
       ...
   }

   public void doSomething() {
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      MyClass myClass = new MyClass(args[0]);
      myClass.doSomething();
   }
}
```

So your main method simply interprets the incoming arguments (as file names or similar), then instantiates and executes your class as another library might.

Comment: That's how my program is written, apparently there was some confusion with the test, eclipse was probably running the class and not the test, I've restart it and it went as predicted.